# AdminLte - How to Force Sidebar to not close

Tags: bootstrap-4, adminlte

[I Want to maintain de sidebar like this in any resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbktW.png)

The way I want to maintain:

```
<body class="sidebar-mini layout-fixed text-sm sidebar-collapse sidebar-closed" style="height: auto;">
```

But the body class change automatically when the resolution changes or in mobile mode:
The property "sidebar-closed" is created.

```
<body class="sidebar-mini sidebar-collapse sidebar-closed" style="height: auto;">
```

I want to force AdminLTE to never close the sidebar.